# static data-type select to dynamic select

Tags: java, php

How can I make this fetched data-type select to a dynamic select that retrieves its options from sql database?

Here is a part of my code hope I can get some solutions and answers to my difficult question.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

function fetch_product_data()
{
 $.ajax({
 url:"fetch.php",
 method:"POST",
 dataType:"json",
 success:function(data)
 {
 for(var count=0; count<data.length; count++)
 {
 var html_data = '<tr><td>'+data[count].id+'</td>';
 html_data += '<td data-name="item_code" class="item_code" data-
 type="select" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].item_code+'</td>
 </tr>';
 $('#product_data').append(html_data);
 }
}
})
 }
$('#product_data').editable({
container: 'body',
selector: 'td.item_code',
url: "update.php",
title: 'Item_code',
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
source: [{value: "Code1", text: "Code1"}, {value: "Code2", text: "Code2"}],
validate: function(value){
if($.trim(value) == '')
{
 return 'This field is required';
}
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't care if ones English isn't fluent, I can read past that. But your lack of effort in making this question makes it unanswerable. Where is the relevant PHP code, where is the returned json data to show us the format? And did you read this code yourself? Did you take a look at the javascript error console because the colors at `data-pk` are not matching probably making your code not run at all.

Comment: And where is the java code?